# Cplex: how to display this linear program in Cplex

Tags: constraints, linear-programming, cplex, docplex, docplexcloud

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7bpx.png)
How do i write this constraints in CPLEX (linear-program)?
∑ j∈M until ∑ k=i xaijk ∗ bkj = dai, ∀i ∈ N, ∀a ∈ B ∩ A1; until = min(i + va, n)

Comment: What CPLEX interface or API are you using? C, C++, Java, C#, OPL, LP file, MPS file? Or some 3rd party tool like AMPL?

Answer (score 0):

In OPL you can write

```
int n=10;
range N=1..n;


{int} A={1,3,5};

int v[A]=[0,1,2];

range M=1..4;

int b[N][M]=[[1,1]];
int d[A][N]=[[1,2]];

dvar boolean x[A][N][M][N];

subject to
{
  forall(i in N,a in A) sum(j in M,k in N:k <=minl(n,i+v[a])) x[a,i,j,k]*b[k,j]==d[a,i];
}
```